# Online meetings: share a virtual small screen (1920x1080) instead of my real big screen (3840 x 1600)

Tags: resolution, zoom-meeting, google-meet

I'm using a really big screen (32inch - 3840 x 1600), it works well for me,
but when I join online meeting with colleagues (through Google Meet, Microsoft Teams, Zoom etc..) and I need to share screen (to demo something), they can't see my content, because they often using small laptop (14 inch - 1920x1080 with 150% display scale)

How could I share a small virtual screen and share it through online meeting application like Google Meet / Microsoft Teams / Zoom / etc.?

The option to "Share Window" doesn't work because I need to switch between multiple windows when demo.

Comment: Because of the multiple windows you need, it may be most workable to use a Virtual Machine for your meetings.  You need the apps and tools inside the VM.

Comment: What platform are you running? If you are on something linux based you can do something with Xnest or Xephyr. If on windows, possibly there are similar programs that let you do the same thing, without the need to run a full VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are demoing an application, most screen-sharing applications
allow to share only the application's window, whose size you can control.

For sharing a part of the screen,
you could use as one solution the open-source project
[ScreenAreaShare](https://github.com/mPyKen/ScreenAreaShare),
that has builds for multiple platforms (not all were tested):

> ScreenAreaShare allows sharing selected area of the screen in
> applications that do not natively support this feature such as Teams.
>
> **How It Works**
>
> ScreenAreaShare creates 2 windows. The capture window is a
> click-through, transparent window indicating the recording area via a
> red border. The rendering window displays the content of that area. In
> applications such as Teams, you can then share the rendering window.